# If $V$ does not depend on $t$, how to show $V_{t} = V_{t+s}$, for $s\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: lie-groups, partial-derivative, symmetry

I am reading a paper, and it says the following:

Let $V = V(x(t))$, i.e., a function of state $x(t)$ but not depend explicitly on $t$.

Now consider a mapping $$\tilde{t} = t+s, $$for any $s\in \mathbb{R}$. So a time shift. The paper says that "under this change of variables, $V_{\tilde{t}}=V_t$." So my question is

> How to show $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial \tilde{t}}$$

What I am thinking is $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \tilde{t}} = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow0} \frac{ V\big(x(t+\Delta t)\big)- V\big(x(t)\big)}{\Delta t+s}$$ However, I cannot see how it can become $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Say hello to the chain rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the chain rule, \begin{align*}V_{\tilde{t}} &= V_{x}x_{\tilde{t}} \\ &= V_{x}x_{t}t_{\tilde{t}} \\ &= V_{x}x_{t}(1) \qquad \text{(since $t = \tilde{t}-s$ and $s$ is constant)} \\ &= V_{x}x_t \\ &= V_t\end{align*} as claimed.